# Will AVR stabilize the flow of current?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

In our village, the power supply is unstable. Sometimes it goes weak, sometimes not. You can tell it by our bulbs, it goes dimmer when the power is weak. Our monitor now shows some green and red wires in the screen, kinda like a 3D screen without a 3D glasses. According to the technician, it was due to the unstable flow of current/power in our village. Now, I have a laptop, and I bought an Auto Voltage Regulator, will this prevent my laptop from being damaged by the unstable flow of currents? Or should we buy our own generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to protect yourself from:

- Over-voltage (which it sounds like what your AVR is for - it just trims voltage down when it's over).
- Under-voltage (which often uses a battery and an inverter - when the voltage goes too low, it *switches* to the battery).

You need to determine which are part of your problems and fix them.

Generally speaking, under-power doesn't cause damage (and, in the case of incandescent light bulbs, actually increases their life).

Over-power is what kills things (like your laptop's charger, a monitor, etc).

And this is where things get complicated.

- If your house looks like a resistor, then voltage and current are linearly related and the AVR can quickly suppress any over-power issues.
- If your house looks like an inductor (hint: most houses do because of all the motors running), then the voltage will lead the current, and the AVR will still be able to trim the voltage.
- If your house looks like a capacitor (I think this is unlikely), then the AVR isn't particularly useful for protecting your laptop against a bad power grid.

Another note: most modern electronics use switching-mode-power-supplies, which are good at handling surges (a good rule of thumb: if its label says it can natively handle 110-240V at 50/60Hz, then it's most likely a SMPS). Legacy transformer-based power supplies are not.

Answer (score 0):

shortly, your laptop charger is a voltage regulator by itself. A voltage regulator is designed to automatically maintain a constant voltage level . it converts the main line voltage (230V for example ) to a voltage for your battery needs ( 12 volts for example - you can know that from charger specs -)

[image]

as you can see in the picture, even if the output voltage is varying in the range of (110V to 250V) the output still going to be the same 19.5 volt with a current rating of 1.58 A

Comment: what if I remove my laptop battery and use the charger directly, will the charger still act like a voltage regulator?

Comment: @BinurikiClieanJay it works this way, the total adapter current is divided into 2 paths, one to the laptop and one to the battery. the laptop has a higher priority and then the rest of the current will go to charge the battery, so no harm of connecting the charger directly.

Comment: @BinurikiClieanJay but this is useless, I mean today's batteries are smart enough to know when to stop charging the battery and maintaining a good lifetime for your battery. unless you have a good reason to connect the adapter to the laptop directly (maybe the battery is not working at all), you don't have to do that